# Planning a database describing a multi-versioned product

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to databases, so I apologize in advance for a noob question.

I need to plan a database logging print jobs performed by some printers. These printers come in multiple versions, and each version may produce different sets of fields in the job log. However, some of these fields will be the same in logs produced by all printer versions.
A very simplified example would be:

Printer version 1.0 may produce log record with the following fields:
[Job ID], [Date], [Printer Version], [Media Height], [Media Width]

While version 2.0 may produce these:
[Job ID], [Date], [Printer Version], [Cyan Toner Used (mg)], [Magenta Toner Used (mg)], [Yellow Toner Used (mg)], [Black Toner Used (mg)]

All this log data should be saved in the same database and the users may run queries on only one printer version, on several or even on all printer versions (for example, a query asking to return all jobs within a certain time period, regardless of the printer or its version). In addition, there will be some calculations, of various percentages, etc.

New printer versions may appear in the future, each with its set of fields, and it is currently unknown which fields will stay common among all the printers.

How should I approach this? This is not a traditional Employer/Employee database scenario, since we're dealing here with basically the same conceptual objects (print job records), with slight variations thereof. So should I...:

1. ...create a single database for all printer versions? But then there will be nulls in fields for printers that don't provide data for these fields.
2. ...define a table for each printer version? But then there will be identical fields appearing in all of them (like [Date]). Wouldn't that be kind of wasteful?
3. ...define a core table containing all common fields ([Job ID], [Date], [Printer Version] in the example) plus other tables (one for each version) containing the fields unique to that version? But which fields will be common in the future is unknown.
4. any other ideas?

Of course I need to take into consideration performance issues, since these tables will grow very large over time (millions of records). Not many users though. And... I'm doing all of this on Access.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Research**

To solve this problem I would first do some research into print jobs, in particular is there already a standard out there that you can just make use of?  or even a tool that already solves what you need?

**2. Search criteria**

If there is no standard out there already that you can make use of, I would try to identify how would the users want to search/query/summarise the print job data that you are looking to log.  These common fields would become the main data elements that you would want on your central table.

**3. Key value pairs**

To get a completely generic set of print job attributes, you will probably need some kind of key value pairs, this could be done either via:

- Key/value table structure, ie:

  - Generic list of fields
  - Mapping table to show which fields are valid for which printer/version
  - Your actual log table to record the field and value for the actual print job

example table structures:

```
TABLE [PrinterVersion] ( [ID] INT, [PrinterType] VARCHAR(100), [PrinterVersion] ...)
TABLE [PrintJobFields] ( [ID] INT, [FieldName] VARCHAR(100), [FieldType] ...)
TABLE [PrinterVersionFields ( [PrintJobFieldID] INT, [PrinterVersionID] INT, [Required] BOOLEAN )
TABLE [PrinterJobValues] ( [PrintJobFieldID] INT, [Value] NVARCHAR(1000) )
```

- XML data field on your print job table

Comment: Wow, that's a **very** generic solution. I'm not sure if we need it that generic, as it doesn't make for a very readable database in this manner. But I'll keep it in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @user3887585 Yes it's a generic solution, as you did highlight several times that the common fields are unknown.  I would however only go with that option if you cannot first find answers using the first 2 recommendations (on the research side, I will be **very** surprised if there isn't some standard out there already).

Comment: I've looked, and apparently there isn't such a standard, at least not for printers. Do you think that if I go with this kind of solution (vertical DB organization as opposed to regular horizontal one), the performance of things like SELECT queries will be affected and won't they have to grow much more complex and/or require much more code around them? After all in the end these queries will have to return data organized conventionally (in rows). Also, with this type of data organization one can't rely on internal Access field typing anymore, since all the fields will have to be text.

Comment: You make a very good point on the complexity of queries, going for a completely generic solution means you'll need to move a lot more of the logic into the application layer (otherwise it does become a nightmare in your queries, there are development patterns out there already to handle this in your app layer).  First though I would look at how you want to query/search and those would become your standard columns...  It's the question of how to handle the list of non-standard fields...

Comment: Well, I think I'll go with the horizontal solution, adding custom columns by code. I'll ignore the fact that certain columns appear in multiple tables, and will manage their collection in a separate table. The code will have to grow a bit complex, but I think it's a good trade-off. Vertical solution is far too complicated for my needs and also may slow things down. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A third solution would be to store everything in a giant `JobData`table that has enough fields to cover all possible printers (at least for now).

You can then have a separate `PrinterConfig` table that has a record for each printer type and, for each field available in the master table stores a boolean value to indicate whether that field is in use or not.
That can be helpful to help you show or hide fields in a report/datasheet to display the data for a given printer.

Of course, in all the examples people have given you so far, you have to decide whether you want a future-proof system, one where you spend a lot of time upfront in the design of the app to make it completely generic, or if you are ok with having to maintain and add more fields later as new printers may require.

There is no right answer here: it's going to be a trade-off. When you have a schema-less or a dynamic data schema, storing and querying data in a Relational Database isn't going to be easy.

You can make your system adapt automatically by creating new fields as necessary, but you still have to build the app to be able to adapt to that lack of static data structure.

In any case, it's going to require a fair amount of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably store the consistent fields in one table:

```
[Job ID], [Date],[Printer Version]
```

And all then split apart the remaining details and store them vertically in a separate table:
[Job ID] [Detail]   [value]

So based on your first example, in your first table you'd have the ID, etc, in the second table, you'd have rows like so:

```
    [Job ID]   [Detail]         [Value]
    ________________________________________
    <job id>   <media height>     <x>
    <job id>   <media width>      <y>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done in this scenario, since types of details may be different, they can't all be text, for instance. But thanks anyway!